# I'm getting some unexpected behaviour with a checkboxGroupInput in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny - a lot I don't fully understand yet.  I'm working on a Shiny app to display some data.  I want to allow for optional filtering of the data before being plotted.  In order to construct my criteria, the UI will supply some `selectInput`s.  My plan is that these are initially disabled.  I could add, to the UI, buttons to activate each `selectInput` independently.  But I wanted to try and use a `checkboxGroupInput` for this task.  To begin developing this, I tried working on just one of the `checkboxGroupInput` values enabling/disabling just one of the `selectInput`s.  It works perfectly except for one specific case.  If I select the targeted `checkboxGroupInput`, the targeted `selectInput` gets enabled.  But if I deselect that targeted `checkboxGroupInput`, the targeted `selectInput` does not get disabled.  However, this behavior only occurs if no other `checkboxGroupInput` selection is currently selected.  If any, or multiple, other `checkboxGroupInput`s are selected, the target will enable and disable in exactly the way I want and expect based on my (limited) understanding of the code.

Below is (hopefully) a clear and simple piece of code to demonstrate this behavior.  I have a `checkboxGroupInput` with four items, and 4 `selectInput`s.  Checking the third `checkboxGroupInput` item is supposed to enable the third `selectInput`.  Unchecking (deselecting) the third `checkboxGroupInput` item is supposed to disable the third `selectInput`.  Again, it behaves in precisely this way - if at least one other `checkboxGroupInput` is selected.  The third `selectInput` will always be enabled by selecting the third `checkboxGroupInput`, but deselecting the third `checkboxGroupInput` item will not disable the third `selectInput` unless at least one other item is currently selected in the `checkboxGroupInput`.

I added output of the currently selected `checkboxGroupInput` contents to try and understand what was happening.

Last thing before the code -- I also first constructed the `checkboxGroupInput` using `choices` instead of `choiceNames` and `choiceValues`; didn't seem to matter.  Also, my first try with the conditional test in the 'if' block was to use `is.element` instead of `%in%`; again, no difference in behavior.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# Let's make lists for the drop boxes

list_1 <- list("a", "b", "c")
list_2 <- list("d", "e", "f")
list_3 <- list("g", "h", "i")
list_4 <- list("j", "k", "l")

# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs

    # Application title
    titlePanel("What's wrong with this??"),

    # Sidebar
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          checkboxGroupInput("enabled", "Search Filters to Enable:",
                             choiceNames = list("List_1", "List_2", "List_3", "List_4"),
                             choiceValues = list("List_1_chosen", "List_2_chosen", "List_3_chosen", "List_4_chosen")),
                             
        # Input: Select from the following lists - default behavior is they are all disabled to start
        disabled(selectInput("List_1_choice", "Choose from List 1:",
                    choices = list_1)),
        disabled(selectInput("List_2_choice", "Choose from List 2:",
                    choices = list_2)),
        disabled(selectInput("List_3_choice", "Choose from List 3:",
                    choices = list_3)),
        disabled(selectInput("List_4_choice", "Choose from List 4:",
                    choices = list_4)),
        verbatimTextOutput("text_choice")),
    
        # Show a plot
        mainPanel(
               # empty
        )
    )
 )

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

# This output is so I can see what's selected in the checkboxGroupInput    
    output$text_choice <- renderPrint({
      return(paste0(input$enabled))})
    
    observeEvent(input$enabled, {

    # Here's the problem (I think) -- this 'if' block is not working the way I expect
      if("List_3_chosen" %in% input$enabled){
        enable("List_3_choice")
        }else{
        disable("List_3_choice")
        }
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have lot's of workarounds to complete this project, but I would very much like to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Help!  And thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When nothing is selected, `checkboxGroupInput` returns `NULL`. You need to explicitly tell the `observeEvent` to not ignore it:

```
  observeEvent(input$enabled, {
    # Here's the problem (I think) -- this 'if' block is not working the way I expect
    if("List_3_chosen" %in% input$enabled){
      enable("List_3_choice")
    }else{
      disable("List_3_choice")
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

Comment: That is beautiful, and makes clear sense.  Just tried; problem solved.  Thank you so much for your time